# Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

For [several months now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow), we've had a close reason (actually an off-topic reason, but no matter) for poorly-asked debugging questions:

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

This is a subset of "unclear what you're asking" that focuses on specific requirements for [folks seeking help with debugging their code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions). I gotta be honest: I don't use this much, purely because it's faster to click "unclear what you're asking". [But a recent discussion here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back) indicated that a good many folks simply don't realize that this reason (or "unclear...") apply to these questions at all! That's not great.

[One of the answers in that thread suggested adding an explicit debugging close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/257887#257887). The suggestion was long, but perhaps that's what's needed to achieve clarity here; I've re-worked it a bit:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

To be clear: debugging questions [**can be useful to others**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions) - but they need to identify a specific problem clearly enough for others to *find* them (and for duplicates to be identified when applicable). Without that, they're just a waste of time and space. My hope is that this reason is more acceptable to folks who disagreed with [my rather broad interpretation of "unclear"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/258062#258062)...

**This reason has now been activated, replacing the previous "lacks sufficient information" off-topic reason.** Thoughts?

Comment: Personally I'd like to see more emphasis on the reproducible in the question part - useful for link only questions and the important bit of what makes a "debug for me" question worth keeping around.

Comment: Done, @Flexo - had to re-work this a bit to get in under 400 chars anyway.

Comment: That would be **great**, +1. Perhaps people who have their questions closed like that would also benefit from some rubber ducking while trying to improve the question should they aim for reopening.

Comment: This will be an extra close reason or will it replace *lacks sufficient information*?

Comment: It would replace *lacks sufficient information*, @rene. It could be considered a superset of that reason, or... we can just keep using "Unclear" for those. As mentioned, I like the expediency of "Unclear"

Comment: Oh god yes please! Also, I was just about to ask this (only, I suck at phrasing a lot more than you)

Comment: Yup. Looks good. Why isn't it there yet?

Comment: the only thing this really adds over the "unclear" reason is it specifically references debugging, right? I guess it kinda gives a more detailed reason to the asker, but it's really no different. If it fits that close reason, it already fits unclear.

Comment: @KevinB The problem is that people don't know the extent of that close reason, so questions aren't being closed.

Comment: If it is to replace the current "Unclear..." choice then I would remove the specific target at "debugging help" to perhaps just generic "help"  so that it can cover the whole range of too much or two little information provided issues.

Comment: Then it's just a duplicate of "unclear", @indivisible. Which already exists and is one less click to use.

Comment: I use *lacks sufficient information* for questions where I miss a table structure or the server part in a client/server bug, so basically it lacks info from other parts of the infrastructure of the OP to answer the question. If this new reason comes live I'm not sure if the type of questions I described earlier still fit within the current text proposal.

Comment: @Shog9, "Unclear" to me means that you cannot work out what the OP is asking specifically and is its own case. In my mind this would be for questions that do have a clear request but either do not supply enough information to find the cause or too much so that wading through it all would be unlikely for most readers. Perhaps I need to re-read the proposal here again...

Comment: @rene "the shortest code **necessary to reproduce**"

Comment: Don't see why this doesn't apply there, @rene: you're still asking for the same three things, *problem*, *desired behavior*, and *test case*.

Comment: @Shog9 I guess rene's point is that while some issues can be reproduced just from seeing the code, for others you need both information about the *code* and the *environment* (e.g. config, table structures, operating system, interpreter being used) in which that code is executed. The wording here (which specifically refers to ***code*** necessary to reproduce) makes this close reason feel inappropriate for cases where what's missing is actually information about the *environment* instead of the *code*. A question asker may reasonably protest *"but I DID include all the code necessary!"*

Comment: Yeah, I think we have to make a trade-off there, @Mark; we made that MCVE page (which includes advice on including configs and so on) as short as possible, but it's still 8x longer than this close reason can be. Missing / excessive / incorrect code is the common case; there's always the opportunity to just leave a comment if the actual omission is something else.

Comment: Big fan of this. Clarity to the poster should be top priority. This should be accompanied by a separate "We're not going to make your new feature for you" close reason.

Comment: It is "Too localized".  Wonder how many more you are going to add.  Today I used a custom close reason: "This question appears to be off topic because it is already covered by twenty million Google hits".  Produced by googling the question title.  Your "we trust you to add good content but not remove bad content" attitude is pretty tiresome.

Comment: Makes no difference who I trust, @Hans. Water always flows downhill; if you're lucky you keep it from undermining the foundations on its way. "Too localized" was meaningless, so folks made it mean whatever they felt like; trying to capture those meanings in specific reasons has been as troublesome as damming a river.

Comment: I suppose these kind of comments are effective, people don't talk back to their Chinese fortune cookie.

Comment: If you want more than a comment, ask a question @Hans.

Comment: Not enough. The very important "include the debugging steps you have taken" is missing. The point would be to help people learn debugging themselves, not by teaching them, but at least letting them know this is what they need. I would still close a question having "desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce" if the OP clearly have not even tried basic debugging. I could do that with the previous close reason, can I do that with this one?

Comment: There's [a great blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) linked to from MCVE regarding that, @kapa... *"StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story"* Much as I'd like to, I don't think we're gonna teach folks to debug in 400 characters; either they've already done it, got stuck, and have a specific problem in hand, or... They need to go do it.

Comment: If you do this, please allow gold badge holders to wield it alone!

Comment: We had a good close reason that identified the need for a SSCCE.  It was explicit in what was needed.  You eliminated it.   [It should never have been eliminated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason).

Comment: If you're talking about the "minimal understanding" close reason, then you're wrong, @Robert - that one never even linked to SSCCE, and certainly wasn't meant for cases where one was required. If you're talking about the "problems with code you've written" reason, then that one was re-written to reference an internal page, as the author of SSCCE objected to its use here (he never intended it for that purpose) - see the discussion here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta

Comment: I was talking about the close reason that identified the need for a SSCCE, just as my first sentence indicates.  We no longer have one that is that clearly written or that explicit.  The vagueness of its replacement is exactly the subject of this question (in my opinion - it's the reason I use in replacement of that other one.)

Comment: Again, the SSCCE guidance was not written for SO, @Robert. That doesn't make it bad advice, but it did make it a bad fit for a close reason. [This discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258856/questions-must-describe-the-specific-problem-and-include-valid-code-to-reprod) by the SSCCE's author is also relevant.

Comment: I like the new wording to encompass more low quality questions.  I just have one concern now.  When reviewing, we have several "eras" of SO history.  That is at one period a time Question A was not valid, but then a few years later it was valid, but then a few years later it was not valid again.  How are we to handle this phenomenon?  Does this new option apply to every question ever asked now?

Comment: Philosophically, yes @demongolem - but practically-speaking, it's better to focus on new, unanswered questions as that's where it'll do the most good.

Comment: Sorry to be a bore, but I think I see questions that lack sufficient information but are *not* debugging questions. For example, someone comments a question about some fancy file handling to say "do you mean on Windows or on Linux?", because the answer ain't gonna be portable. The questioner doesn't respond. What's the close reason now, "unclear"? Not that I disapprove, I think such questions are rarer than the ones that *are* about debugging.

Comment: Unclear questions are still unclear; if the question lacks sufficient information for an effective answer without first going on a fishing expedition (or developing psychic powers) then close it @Steve.

Comment: The new close reason is much better, thanks.

Comment: I miss the old good **`This question appears to be off-topic, because it lacks sufficient information.`**

Comment: I have a question about the phrase "Questions seeking debugging help".  Can I use this excuse for a "Here is my problem, go write it for me" type of a question?  It would help to have the term "minimal example" without the debugging phrase in this case since there is nothing to debug.

Comment: Is it really a superset of the "lacks sufficient information"? Looks more like a subset to me, hence [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/1258041) of mine.

Comment: No, there should simply maybe be a side for "why isn't it working?" questions for people that searched their code for hours and kind find the mistake. But that should be a stackoverflow chat or some other page that user don't just stumble upon via google so that it won't get flooded with beginner questions that can be solved through existing s.o. questions (this is the only time I think beginners could otherwise create a problem).

Answer (score 125):

**Update:** Thank you for taking community feedback seriously. This is now live!

I'll try to update this answer with usage experience. I've made this "Community Wiki". Everyone is welcome to edit in their experiences with it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122169/server-error-in-application-existing-connecction-forcibly-closed-by-remote-h close voted with this reason. Looks like a great fit.
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/24131061/1348195

---

Yes, I definitely think this is a good idea.

- **"Unclear" is ambiguous** - The fact over 500 people have upvoted [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back) clearly shows that a lot of people, me included do **not** use "Unclear" as a close reason for those questions as you've intended.
- **The specific use case you describe is very common** - having clearer guidelines on it can be very helpful. It can make the choice of closing or keeping open obvious.
- **This close reason is clear** - I think we have established that close reasons should be as clear as possible with all the discussion and abuse of "lacks minimal understanding". This is definitely a step in the right direction.
- **It's polite** - it does not imply anything about the *author* but rather focuses on *the question* which is huge in my opinion. We shouldn't criticize the author themselves, but the question.
- **It's helpful** - it points the OP to the resources comments would point them to otherwise, and it describes the steps to mitigate the problem precisely. "Unclear" is nothing like this.

Comment: "Very" = 80% of front-page questions.

Comment: [Funny you should mention that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so), @bjb568...

Comment: I also support this; not that the community has much weight in decisions. If it comes from Shog, it is "featured", if it is just upvoted by the community a lot, that is sadly a different story.

Comment: @Final I don't know what you are trying to say, but it sounds like you're saying that the community doesn't have a lot of weight in decisions. That isn't true at all. I do more than my fair share of complaining, but Shog is an *awesome dude* who definitely *does* listen to community feedback. The evidence is right here in this question—do read it again more carefully. He links to [this recent Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/), where there was an outpouring of community support for bringing a close reason like the one he's proposing back. Clearly he listened.

Comment: @CodyGray: one case does not clarify many. I am afraid it is you who should read meta more often. There are plenty of upvoted proposals (majority eventually) that go nowhere. No, many of them are not even development related, just mindset which can be already achieved with existing tools. I am grateful when some progress is occasionally made, but on the contrary, I am sad for the majority.

Comment: @FinalContest: if Stack Overflow were a democracy where the majority ruled, we'd allow awful subjective questions, demands to write askers' entire programs for them, and there'd be no downvotes or closing questions.

Comment: @Wooble: there is a difference between majority (which can be 51%, too) and pretty much everyone, but at least the most valuable contributors. I am talking about situations as the latter. Also, I must personally admit that I do not think the majority of the contributors here on meta agree about "no downvotes" and "no closures". I am convinced about the opposite.

Comment: This question is "featured" because the last time I changed close reasons on SO a lot of folks felt blindsided by the change, @Final - so I'm gonna leave this up for comment over the weekend, respond to feedback, make any needed corrections, and if there are no credible objections make the change on Monday once everyone's had a chance to think about it. This isn't just about the folks on meta; even small changes like this have a big effect on the entire site.

Comment: I think this change is really great. Now I have valid close reasons for all questions that I think should be closed. This is a good thing.

Answer (score 65):

Hell yes. Please, please give us this.

It's like the old

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

close reason, only it *also* contains a clause about making the code sample minimal...

> *the shortest code necessary*

... which means that we can legitimately use it on wall-of-code debugging questions that are theoretically answerable but where the question asker has provided 100 lines of code to show us an issue that could have been demonstrated in one or two lines.

One thing that puts me off doing more close vote reviewing is that I can't close answerable-but-crap wall-of-code debugging questions without either crafting custom close reasons or abusing the *unclear what you're asking* reason in a way that will leave the question asker confused. You're solving that problem, and that's awesome.

On a tangential note, I also seriously like the idea of

> not useful to other readers

appearing in the publicly facing close reasons. It helps to make clear that Stack Overflow does not primarily exist to serve the original question asker - that we're happy if you get help here, but that you need to make sure that your questions are providing value to the internet and not just to you.

Comment: @Alicia just to clarify, "not useful to other readers" is a quote from Shog's new close reason - I was commenting approvingly upon the existing proposal, not offering a new one.

Answer (score 21):

(I think that maybe I misinterpreted the question being asked, but I'm going to post my thought anyways because I'm wondering if other newer members to the community might share a similar thought.)

Honestly, when I see the whole:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

business, I'm confused.

Seeing 'off-topic' in big bold letters when the question is clearly ON topic (or rather, a question relevant to the Stack community it got posted in) makes me think that the question doesn't belong.

I don't think about 'because it lacks sufficient information' or it needs more information (however anyone wants to specify this), I think about the word 'off-topic' and what it means and it took me a while to catch on that off-topic is kind of a catch-all for marking topics that ARE off-topic or topics that need more information etc.

That said, when I read this question (because I was searching for why 'insufficient information' gets labeled as 'off-topic'), I totally read it from the 'does off-topic make sense when using it to describe a topic that needs more information' angle.

(And no, it doesn't make sense at all.)

Comment: You're not the first person to be confused about this. We started discussing it as soon as the changes were made to the close reasons that lumped all these under "off topic". See: [Shouldn't "off-topic" be only about... off-topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086), [Some custom off-topic close reasons don't really describe off-topic questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186635), [Can we rename the off-topic close reason label?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024),  [How about a slight change to the wording around off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193668), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the links - I really appreciate it; somehow when I was searching (on second thought, I think I was searching in the wrong SE region), it wasn't wanting to pull up those topics.  It's also relieving to know that I'm not the only one who has gotten confused.

Comment: The discussion occurred before the split between Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. So yes, there are lots of gems that you'll need to search Meta Stack Exchange for now. And it isn't always as easy as searching, unless you remember having read them to start with. :-)

Comment: Definitely agree with this. The new close reason seems great but still having it use that strange terminology is needlessly confusing

Answer (score 13):

Update: Thank you for not taking community feedback seriously. This is now live but expectedly useless. As long as majority misinterprets the purpose of the site, to get 5 votes is still a problem, almost unsolvable.

## No, thanks.

*Alone* this reason could help nothing.

We should have either a *hammer* for this, or *allow* these questions freely.

There are way too many people around, who gladly will spoil the whole idea, either plain rep-whores or just ones who mistake both the purpose of the site and the meaning of the word "help".

You are again addressing the wrong problem.

It is not lack of the proper reason. It is the *speed* at which lazy questions are being answered and accepted. And the awful inefficiency of traditional quorum-based closure mechanism on the other hand. The latter one is utterly inadequate compared to the former. Which *is* the real problem.

These questions asking for a "second pair of eyes" is a most delicious prey for the rep-whores - no knowledge nor research nor time to write required - but just fast on-site examination. To fight hasty answers, one need a closure tool of *comparable* speed.

On the other hand, there are indeed cases when one gets stuck and needs but a pair of fresh eyes. The authorities should definitely think of the service for this kind of help.

Comment: I [largely agree with this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/258062#comment36639_258062); in fact, I don't think we should be wasting *anyone's* time on most of these, as they can be detected and blocked (with appropriate guidance) before being posted. But given that logic is still in the design stages, this'll have to suffice until it can be implemented.

Comment: @Shog9 He does have a point though. I've [been advocating for giving trusted users more weight to their close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257881/reward-close-vote-reviewers-show-them-the-top-voted-questions-for-the-day/257886#257886). I'm not sure how you would quantify trusted, but this would help get crap closed quicker & provide help to the user on how to improve faster.

Comment: @hichris123: trusted users already have more close vote weight. All we need is 1 catch all question that says "Halp my codez don't works" with no detail and then we can dupe-hammer all the underspecified questions as duplicates of it.

Comment: I think the last paragraph deserves some special consideration. I've been fighting with a very hard to debug OS problem for almost a week, but I'm hesitant to ask for help, even though I'm sure someone on StackOverflow knows the solution.

Comment: @dauphic If you've really been working to debug the problem yourself, it is probably fine to ask about it on Stack Overflow. You are not the intended target of this close message. You will have a self-contained minimal example to show, you'll be able to describe the problem clearly, etc.

Answer (score 9):

100% agreed with this new close reason.

I was "brought up" here under the impression that this site is for people who have at the minimum, a vague knowledge of what they are doing. Without a minimal understanding, we have a flood of poorly asked, unclear questions.

People who wish to learn are ALWAYS TO BE ACCEPTED anywhere, which is in my opinion, why the chats are here. My questions were bad starting up on Stack, but I had a desire to learn and better myself. So I went to the JavaScript chat, and now I'm a room owner teaching others (within a year!!).

So this new close method may hopefully drive more eager learners (it's easy to filter out help vamps there) to the chats where the learning is dynamic, and the Main is cleaner and clearer than ever.