# What to do when OP won't provide additional code but instead provides a link and login credentials

Tags: discussion

Recently I came across a question where the OP has clearly stated the problem and expected behaviour for the solution.

However the code snippet does not capture the problem. Myself and 2 other users have asked the OP to provide the client side code.

In response to the requests the OP has provided a URL to his/her site and login credentials in order to access the page where the problem JavaScript code can be found.

How should such a question be handled?

The credentials and URL are provided in the comments. Should those comments be deleted by the community to help protect the OP?

Comment: Post the login credentials on your social network of choice?

Comment: Just to add to @ThisSuitIsBlackNot 's suggestion, post it on 4Chan's /b/ channel.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Vote or flag to close the question as "Unclear what you're asking".

If you want to be extra-specific, [there's an off-topic reason for this as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions):

[image: Questions seeking debugging help]

Comment: Thanks Shog9. I have slightly expanded the question to included the fact that the OP left the credentials in the comments.

Comment: @robbmj note the second highlighted passage in the close reason: "in the question itself."  Having code elsewhere doesn't meet this requirement.  Code elsewhere can disappear and make the question completely useless giving poor results to other people who find it and ultimately disregarding the time spent for the answers that are now similarly difficult to use. It is inherently disrespectful to the people answering, the people finding, and the community as a whole to have the code posted on some other service as the only means of accessing it.

Comment: Sometimes there is so much code that posting all in the question is counter productive. Maybe SO should host its own version of pastebin.com for this requirement to make more sense.

Comment: @Dialecticus Most of the time, when there is that much code, it's a poor question, and the OP hasn't done enough work to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Dialecticus That's why the close reason mentions "the shortest code necessary to reproduce it". The hope obviously being they'll cut out unnecessary code (like db access for a UI question, or UI code for a db question).

Comment: @Dialecticus SO has runnable snippets. This makes the bulk of links to pastebin, JSFiddle etc. redundant (at least for the most recent questions).

Comment: @Renan Stack Snippets only work for JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

Comment: Currently SO is the site for professionals and enthusiasts. Beginners, being stupefied even by the smallest programming obstacles will have a hard time here. They exist, though, and they will enthusiastically ask help from SO, only to encounter even more obstacles. Maybe we should just hide them from general population, to calm down the natives.

Comment: @Dialecticus: *"Sometimes there is so much code that posting all in the question is counter productive."* That's when you point them at [making an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dialecticus _"They exist, though, and they will enthusiastically ask help from SO, only to encounter even more obstacles._" Not if they just read the help center and pay attention. I was brand spanking new to programming when I started here. I've had absolutely no trouble because I cared to learn and follow the rules here. The solution isn't to "hide them" just to "calm down the natives" but instead to treat their posts as we would anyone else's in the hopes that they will pay attention to what they are being told and learn from it. If they have too much code, we tell them, they should fix it

Comment: So based on the popularity of the comments on this question. And that my flags on the comments that this question refers to were declined. Should I assume the community has no interest in protecting the OP?

Comment: I deleted the comment, @robbmj - next time use a custom flag & just say "credentials should be removed" or something like that. I doubt these were particularly sensitive though.