# Which close vote to cast on a poor question to have the close reason better help the OP with further steps?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

We all see a lot of poor questions - we don't answer them because they are poor, show no effort etc.. we want the OP to improve the question - sometimes show the current code and attempts before spending more time on it.

But some of them, even though poor and deserve a downvote also deserve a close vote. Now the question is which vote is better for a new user?

I always find it difficult to decide which close reason better suits:

- *`Unclear what you are asking?`* - which after the question gets closed shows how to properly ask a question links etc
- *`why isn't this code working?`* - which after the question gets closed shows links to the mcve.

I know they are 2 different close reasons for a reason but is it just me who finds it difficult to select the more appropriate one?

Are there any guidelines (*except the text directly below the close reason*) which suggest when to go with what reason?

<sub>*Please skip the custom reason for this discussion.</sub>

Comment: I tend to use Unclear if there is no code at all and use the OT reason if there is just a wall of code with no debug effort or where it is not clear what doesn't work.

Comment: "why isn't this code working" close reason is intended to be [for vague debugging questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601)

Comment: And I say [yet again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216677/213957): We need to bring ***not enough effort*** reason back.

Comment: [Another attempt](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/1169519) in a bit different form, but it seems to be buried too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I use the unclear reason when my brain just can't parse what they want.  When they have sentences that seem to contradict each other, when I can't even get a vague idea what they want or whenever I can tell I have that "huh?" look on my face after reading it twice, that's "unclear what you are asking".

When I can at least get a handle on what they want or there appears to be at least a starting point, I go with "why doesn't this work".  If they have explained that they are experiencing a problem with code, have described the problem and what it is or isn't doing, but without code, the "why isn't this working" reason is perfect.  It explicitly states you need to put the code in the question before we can help you.

Like @rene said in the comments, sometimes there are the wall of code questions that just expect us to divine what is wrong and what should be right.  I believe those can go either way.  Since they didn't really ask much of a question (besides "it doesn't work") it is both "unclear what they are asking" and that they "need to include the behavior they are seeing and what the desired behavior should be". (I paraphrased the close reason text a bit, but you get the gist.)  At that point, use your best judgement as to which would help the question more.  Do they need to focus on the "m" in mcve? "Why doesn't this work".  Did they try to describe what they wanted but just failed miserably? "Unclear".  Etc. Etc.  And if both could work equally well, flip a coin.  Bottom line is it should be closed and needs work.

Comment: One's specifically 'code dump; why not working'. It's obvious what they're _asking_ it's just  brain meltingly annoying to debug it for them. 

The other is if I've read their question - post coffee - and can't actually figure out what they want. That's closed as 'unclear'.