# Things to consider when casting close and open votes

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My reputation is approaching the point where I will be able to cast close and re-open votes. I didn't find a META question specifically about this, so I decided to write this.

Certainly, reading the information linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/help is a good place to start, but is there anything else that a newly authorized user should consider when deciding to vote one way or the other in this matter? Are there any anecdotes that stand out in your mind that illustrate a borderline case, and how the decision was made to go to one side or the other?

Comment: Did you already use flags for closure so far?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I have close to 200 flags and only 10 have been declined. Some have been disputed. Most are marked "Helpful".

Comment: Well, the reasonings, -  at least for closing -,  are exactly the same as you have for the flags. It's just the dialog popup changes a bit.

Comment: The reasoning is exactly what the help-center lists on the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) pages. It it's not there, those pages should be made more complete to contain the pertinent information.

Comment: **Please don't close it. Improve it.** Having a step-by-step guide, maybe even a flow diagram, could make this to a very good community wiki post.

Comment: @peterh OP's are the 1st address to improve their questions themselves. Closure tells them to do so and how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which close vote to cast on a poor question to have the close reason better help the OP with further steps?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280525/which-close-vote-to-cast-on-a-poor-question-to-have-the-close-reason-better-help)

Comment: Anecdote time.  I have essentially no interest in moderation.  But every so often I'll run across a question that has been closed for some bogus reason.  Once, I decided to vote to reopen just to see what would happen.  Imagine my surprise when the question was immediately reopened as soon as I clicked.  Heck of a vote I guess.  Someday if I get really bored maybe I'll discover where the moderator documentation is hiding.

Comment: @Cerad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the link.  I sort of thought I was just being lazy but if I really need to read 5 year old questions to learn how the moderation system works then I'm glad I never got interested.  I just think that maybe some sort of dialog box could pop up and explain what it about to happen when you click on this sort of stuff.  Maybe with a "don't show again" checkbox so it does not get overly annoying.  Oh well.  Just because someone is somewhat successful at answering questions does not automatically make them a good moderator.

Comment: @Cerad Well, it's in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), too: *"It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold. (A question can be closed as duplicate with a single vote from a moderator or a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's current tags, unless that user participated in editing the tags.)"* The system also shows a gold badge after your name in the close description box, which has an explanatory tooltip on hover. The idea is, if you've earned a gold badge, you are a subject matter expert, and thus able to judge what is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Certainly, reading the information linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/help is a good place to start, ...

Yes, what's documented in the help center well defines the close reasons for *off-topic* questions, that's merely is it.

As you state in [your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386614/things-to-consider-when-casting-close-and-open-votes#comment707529_386614) regarding your flagging experiences:

> Yes, I have close to 200 flags and only 10 have been declined. Some have been disputed. Most are marked "Helpful".

The only thing that will change is a shortened dialog pop up, that directly leads you to select from the appropriate close reasons. Reasoning stays the same.

> Are there any anecdotes that stand out in your mind that illustrate a borderline case, and how the decision was made to go to one side or the other?

No, there's no such anecdotical reference as far as I know.

If you're unsure you may attend to the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) chat room and ask there.

Reopening is just the reverse process (as that's nothing you can have with your flagging experience already).
If you think that a question should be reopened because you can't see that a close reason was appropriately applied, just vote for reopening.

Comment: "because you can't see that a close reason was appropriately applied" - I would say "because you can't see that *any* close reason *applies to the post in current state*"... Many meta posts about "this closed as too broad and should be closed as missing MCVE" generally recommend not to reopen if still should be closed for different reason.