# Close Vote Review audit failed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was recently in close vote review queue and I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365766/locationclient-class-not-found-on-google-play-services-rev-22) like:

[image: Close Vote Review Queue]

In my opinion, that question don't show any research effort. A search on Google can solve that issue. I thought it should be closed with the reason Off-topic (Why this code not working). So I voted to close.

Unfortunately it was a review audit, and it said my decision was wrong. I'm still thinking that it should be closed.

I still can't figure out why my review audit failed. Can anyone help me on this? I would like to improve my close reviews in future.

I asked the same in [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20539340#20539340) chat.

Comment: *"A search on Google can solve that issue"*  did you make that search ? I guess not otherwise you would have found that the top result on this problem is already an SO post (the question should be closed as duplicate,  but it is certainly not off-topic)

Comment: @ben75: Okay, I agree. I didn't even choose the option for closing. Before that it said your review audit failed. I'm actually concerned about the review audit decision.

Answer (score 4):

Uh, there's no code that's being debugged. He's already identified the problem - LocationClient is gone. So, he's done at least that much research.

If you want to be pedantic, you could argue he's not asking much of a question; it's more of an observation, really. But come on, the implied question is "why?" Which is trivially-answerable.

You could also argue it's a duplicate, which would've made this a bogus audit. But, you didn't.

Comment: I'm not arguing, but such kind on review audits causing trouble.

Comment: How is that question even remotely related to this discussion? Your audit has a guy noting that Google *removed the LocationClient API* - **for everyone!** This new guy has an installation problem on his computer. The former can be answered with references to the documentation for the benefit of everyone else who hasn't been following API deprecation; the latter involves debugging someone's installation.

Comment: I don't think you understand. LocationClient isn't unavailable because the asker didn't install the SDK properly. *Everyone* who installs the r22 SDK is going to find it missing. We need to know a lot about the second guy's Xen installation to figure out what's going on; there's a lot of information we don't have. We don't need *any* additional information about the first guy's problem **because anyone who installs the rev 22 SDK can trivially reproduce it!** Adding more information to it would actually make it *worse* by burying the real problem... See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685

Comment: Anyway leave that, I'm not satisfied with that review audit decision (I didn't even choose the option for closing. Before that it said your review audit failed. I'm actually concerned about the review audit decision.). We can have more reasons to argue with you (there are tons of closed question out there in SO which have similar question pattern), but don't want to do that.

Comment: And I'm not satisfied that you're closing questions which you don't understand. Please don't do that. The audits offer you a chance to identify mistakes and learn from them - if you don't, you should avoid reviewing altogether.

Comment: I didn't even choose the reason for closing. Before that it said your review audit failed. I'm actually concerned about the review audit decision

Comment: Talking to SO moderators is a nightmare, they won't accept anything. Anyway I'm taking your advice ( if you don't, you should avoid reviewing altogether.) and don't want to participate in any review queue from now onwards.

Comment: If you need you can check my review history and failed review audit count, it'll be less than 5 or 10. So I'm still not agreeing with you. Anyway thanks for your answer and time.

Comment: I do agree with OP that audits are not nuanced enough. Either they should be more specific with the feedback up front, or they should be more lenient.