# What are the best practices for a good C library linking question

Tags: discussion, questions

To start off: I'm not a programmer. I'm a civil engineer who picked up matlab in school and then scientific python in my career as a means to set myself apart from most other meat-space engineers. Effectively, I know what C/C++ is on a conceptual level, but for this purposes, let's pretend I barely grasp what's going on when I read it.

I'm currently trying to improve a python library (`py1`) that serves as an interface to a pretty mathematically complex C library (`C1`). That C library depends on another C library (`C2`), which depends on ... all the way down to `C4`.

Point is, it's not working somewhere in the compilation/linking/configuration phase. And I don't even know where to begin when it comes to formulating a useful question.

Should I post the header files and the compilation commands in the `makefile`? Is SO even the place for this type of question? ("yes" would be the suprising answer here to me)

I tried searching SO for various incantation of tags that seemed relevant, based on my rudimentary understanding, but couldn't find any good (or highly upvoted) questions that helped me with my issue or serve as a guide as to how to ask a good question.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions

Comment: @gnat thanks for the link. That confirms my suspicions: if there's not a clear path in my mind to make a reproducible example, I can't write a good SO question.

Comment: that's right. On the other hand, since you're trying to fix the issue anyway, chances are good that at some step down that path you _will_ get to the point from where such a question would naturally emerge

Comment: your question in general, sounds more like a *how do I debug this config* rather than succinct programming problem

Comment: Ask a C programmer to ask this question.

Comment: @Plutonix: I think that's a fair assessment. Other the otherhand, I think the fix might be relatively simple (i.e., oh just add `#include <blah>` here. But I'm driving blind and my tinkering has been completely fruitless.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a great idea. Now if I could just find a C programmer...  :/

Comment: you could probably find one in a chat room - they might even give you some pointers on how to debug that config

Comment: @Plutonix I hadn't thought of that. thanks!

Comment: The output of the "make" command probably will be enough to start.

Comment: You could start by isolating out *which* of the "configure/compile/link" phases is failing and concentrating on that. If ntohing else, it might narrow down the search for you enough to hopefully find a solving answer. It's ideal if you can run the phases separately. If not, the name of the program which reports the error should be enough to (let Google) tell whether it's the compiler or linker.