# What is the proper flag for this question?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668437/timeout-while-waiting-for-frame-document-becoming-available-in-watin
as very low quality.  The flag was disputed, which to my understanding is basically denied.

What was the proper flag for this question?

Comment: It was probably disputed through review, likely Triage. (VLQ flags send questions to the Triage queue.) If it was reviewed as "Looks OK" or "Should Be Improved", the flag would have been disputed. I would go with "Too Broad" for that one, since we have absolutely no idea what could cause the error and it could probably be a number of things. "VLQ" doesn't feel like a good fit here, as the question could be fixed up if the OP adds in some code and a bit more explanation.

Comment: Are you trying to "Close" or "Flag"? I'd suggest closing because there are more predetermined options unless you want to manually write in for "Other".

Comment: Thinking about it, the close flag for "Questions seeking debugging help" would probably fit that question as well, as they want to know what's giving them that error without providing their MCVE.

Comment: Is it just better to avoid the very low quality flag when possible?

Comment: I would just use it for utter garbage, really. Questions that cannot possibly be fixed whatsoever. But even then, if you are under 3k, there is a flag option under "Off-Topic" for "Blatantly Off-Topic" that would work. A good use-case would be a question written in a language other than English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)

Comment: "Disputed" means disputed, not denied.  It means that other community members saw things differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A close vote of off-topic, with the qualifier

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

would seem to be the best fit here, since they did not provide any code at all for the thing that's timing out. There's no real way to help them until they do.

We're having a bit of a problem lately with the way that "Should Be Improved" triage reviews are invalidating correct flags. [That's what happened here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7711737) ([twice, in fact](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7707042)). Either people are misinterpreting what "Should Be Improved" means, or that vote should not invalidate flags.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph.  Was the flag actually correct, and improperly invalidated by the reviews?  Is that post really unsalvageable, rather than "should be improved?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That's what I'm wondering here. I took "Should Be Improved" to indicate that something could be improved by the community and was thus a good choice for the Help and Improvement queue. This question couldn't possibly be improved by anyone other than the asker themselves, so I didn't think it qualifies for this. If "Should Be Improved" applies to questions that the asker themselves must repair, close votes and close flags on that question shouldn't be invalidated by voting for that option in triage.