# Would my likely Open MPI question be on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I am having problems with running a software on Open MPI. Open MPI throws an error, and I am unable to redirect it to a file currently. I asked a question on Unix - [Standard Error redirect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370848/unable-to-redirect-standard-error-of-openmpi-in-csh-to-file) and it has not attracted any answers so far.

Since I have never worked with Open MPI before I am not sure on how to present the error here so I can get an answer.

Would a vague question on Open MPI usage be on topic here?

Are Open MPI questions on topic on Stack Overflow and if so, is there any extra information I need to provide in such questions to make them answerable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure how that duplicate answers this question, unless you meant it to signal that when the question would be asked on main the guidance from the dupe will be followed and thus the question will be closed, meaning it is off-topic. I'm not not convinced yet that is true.

Comment: @gnat - I understand SE Is not a forum for discussion. I was only exploring possibilities whether SE can help me in this case or not.

Comment: post referred in my prior comment explains what you need to do if you want help with your OpenMPI error at Stack Overflow (@rene that's why I suggested it as a duplicate). For a more general guidance consider giving a read to [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252777/839601)

Comment: @gnat - At the moment I am not even sure how to redirect the OpenMPI error to a file.  If I could do that I am sure I can put up a convincing on topic question

Comment: Show your code, document the error you get.  And [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are already questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openmpi)  tagged [openmpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openmpi), but their general usage seems to be with developers writing code to interface with the OpenMPI library instead of its general usage.  That said, I would be hesitant to think that your question is on-topic here, since there's nothing immediately in your question that only a developer would be able to answer.