# How to flag question without a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example?

Tags: support, questions, flags

Sometimes I found a question were the user hasn't search any information about how to solve his problem, or he is asking how to do something when he didn't show anything, even just a line of code, **anything**, so it's more like if he were asking you to do his work. Which flag is the apropiate for that? I was thinking in something like "Lacks of Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example", maybe I haven't saw it in the flag menu, if that is true I'm sorry, but I didn't find something similar. Actually, I use to flag them as low quality, too broad or unclear, which fit better for the question, but I don't think that is he right thing

Comment: The no MCVE reason is _off-topic_ -> _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")..._. Though _too broad_ is perfectly fine for questions that are basically just code requests.

Comment: see also: [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601)

Answer (score 8):

The MCVE is aimed at *debugging* questions - "I have a problem with my code..." - where the asker hasn't provided enough information to help (or has provided a dump of their entire project, or a screenshot of their editor, or similar nonsense).

That doesn't sound like what you're talking about.

As Mike M notes, questions of the form, "What do I need to build a [secure encryption routine | image editor | Facebook]?" are too broad; an answer could fill several books. There's a close reason for that.

Questions of the form, "How do I do [specific, well-defined task] using [specific, well-defined tools]?" are... Usually fine. Arguably they're what most folks *use* when they use Stack Overflow answers. Leave 'em alone.