# What is best way to demonstrate a problem with a question?

Tags: discussion

I frequently experienced a scenario where a question contains code which doesn't elicit the errors claimed by the asker. People are going back and forth in the comments and the OP insists that the code does what they claim, but it's apparently not the case.

Today I saw someone post an "answer" which was basically an MCVE of the code from the question *proving* that it works fine and doesn't throw any error.

A post like this can prove helpful in that it establishes and makes undeniable a *problem* with the question as it is presented, but to me this isn't really an *answer* and I'm not sure it's appropriate to put it there.  Still, it's frequently what's needed to help draw out the real issue at hand. Is it acceptable to post something like that as an "answer"?  If not, what is the best way to demonstrate something programmatically that's basically a comment, but isn't possible as a comment?

**UPDATE:** Since this has now been closed as a dupe of [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions) - allow me to clarify. I'm asking about how to best demonstrate code issues when that is your intention. This is not about closing debugging questions, it's about the tools we have available to engage in a dialog about code with the OP without using the *answer* format - since frequently these kinds of dialogs involve an exchange of information that may not qualify as an answer.

Comment: For your last question: I typically post a comment linking to an online compiler demonstration that the code is indeed valid. Not sure if this is applicable in the general case though.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - me too but this made me wonder why that should be necessary for something like jfiddle when we already have stack snippets, just no easy way to use them outside of an "answer"... that I'm aware of

Comment: @billynoah Me too. And there are other programming language tags.

Comment: That sounds like a case worthy of the DCM maneuver: Down vote, Close vote, and Move along.

Comment: I see this a lot. And I admit I've done this before. Prove beyond reasonable doubt that the question doesn't demonstrate the problem. Usually I community-wiki the answer so it doesn't lead to (as much) friction. Frankly, if I save a dozen people 5 minutes trying to figure out a problem doesn't exist, I see it as helpful. Question should get downvoted, closed & deleted anyway.

Comment: @jpp and by answering you might grab some upvotes which would keep the question away from the needed cleaning. Not sure for CW though, but I also see a lot of such answers that are not CW, and these get my downvotes.

Comment: @Yunnosch It seems to me this kind of questions are asking *Why* their code doesn't work. Stating that it does work doesn't answer the why. We have a "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include [...] the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" and a "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced". So if you are not able to reproduce the issue of such a question, this question is off-topic and should not be answered but closed.

Comment: @Kaiido Good point. I should have listened to the little voice saying that something is off... ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido, In theory you are right. In practice, I *often* see people guessing at the problem and writing answers accordingly, when no demonstrated problem exists. I too would much rather have the question closed asap. But the current system requires 5 votes (even if they all hold gold badges), sometimes takes far too long.

Comment: @jpp being able to produce an answer from a theoretical problem, and simply state that there is no problem are two different things though.

Comment: @Kaiido, I never denied that. In fact, I [agree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373490/what-is-best-way-to-demonstrate-a-problem-with-a-question?noredirect=1#comment626918_373490). But the tools aren't available for us to deal with these questions *efficiently*.

Comment: For javascript questions in these cases, I'll just add a comment with a link to a js fiddle which proves that their code doesn't produce the error they're describing. If they're not responsive to that or still disagree I'll vote to close as "doesn't provide an MVCE". I agree this sort of thing should not be an answer.

Comment: Won't leaving a comment saying "I can't reproduce this so I'm closing this as lacking MCVE" suffice? People are likely to trust you.

Comment: @user202729 - Sometimes that's best, but at other times, I find the question interesting enough that I feel it's worth pursuing a dialog to get at what's really going on with the OP's code.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is to close as as off-topic -> lacks MCVE. It is the OP's job to make sure that the problem can be reproduced.

Answers are not really there to prove a point in arguments about what the code in the question does/does not. It is better to post a comment and link to an online compiler output etc. We should only write answers when we are certain what the OP is asking for. Answers that are guesses or speculations tend to be bad.

That being said, answers that call out problems with the OP's approach might be acceptable - it is something of a grey area. If the question is a "XY problem" and someone else has answered the question in the way that the OP hoped for, then an answer showing the proper way to solve the problem can be perfectly fine. It will not solve the OP's immediate, short-term problem, but it will be a helpful reference for future readers, so that they don't make the same mistake as the OP did.

Comment: To clarify, I'm asking about *how* to demonstrate issues - not what to do about.  That said, you've touched on some important points here in the second two paragraphs in regards to the appropriateness of putting demos in an answer format.  thanks

Comment: @billynoah Yeah, that would be: "It is better to post a comment and link to an online compiler output etc"

Comment: I'm open to title revisions - feel free to edit my question.  I wasn't sure if we had something on site that wouldn't require linking to off site resources.  Or if posting these kinds of things as an "answer" is actually fine.  It's good to get perspectives since, as you said, there's a bit of a grey area here.