# Why did I get a review ban for this homework help question triage?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

So I received my second review ban in a short period of time and first of all I want to make clear that I am not trying to whine about this but am rather asking here to genuinely learn where I went wrong this time. I like stackoverflow and I want to give back to the community by doing review work.

My first ban was for misunderstanding the "Reqiures Editing" button and I learned from reading a lot about this that many other fell into the same pit as I did and I still think the help text should be adjusted a bit to make it more clear what it is for. However, I learned my lesson there and I am only bringing this up because I think the three other reviews of the question I am talking about went wrong there again:

[Assigning array elements to another array in java [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25534406)

As you can see, I reviewed that this question looks fine because I understood what the question was about and found that it could be answered as is. It looks like a homework assignment, which according to [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) has to include what the author has tried so far and an explanation what the difficulty is. Both are there. Grantedly there is not any code that actually outputs things like he explains the the comment, but still - is that the only reason it was closed? If so, how much time should we give the author to edit his question (after asking him to do so in a comment) before flagging it as off-topic?

I am thinking I do not yet fully grasp the concept of what is off-topic and what is on-topic. The linked above help article also explains that typos should not be answered but are off-topic. Now I [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60421551/5696502) a couple of days ago and one could argue that this is just a typo, and the question was closed afterwards as well. My understanding was however, that the author did not grasp the concept that quotes are necessary at this point even though he outputs the value from PHP. Having said that, I would be happy with deleting my answer, however I wonder where else a question like this should be redirected to, if it is off-topic on stackoverflow?

To sum up, my two questions are:

1. Where did I go wrong with the review of the question I am currently banned for?
2. What should I have done with the "typo-question" rather than answer it?

Comment: Also, from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**... 3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."*

Comment: @Larnu the linked post does not answer my question because as I said from my understanding the question DOES include the required parameters, both what he has done and where he has difficulties - also I did not try and answer the question but only triaged it

Comment: even if that question isn't homework, it don't provide an MRE, nor does the OP show the expected results they are after (only describe). Just because it looks like a Homework question, doesn't mean it'll be closed as one.

Comment: If you're asking why were you review banned, or why was the question closed, that's a somewhat different question to what you ask here.

Comment: @Larnu I am trying to learn why I am review banned. I understood that it was because I went wrong on the linked review. Since I pressed "looks OK" it seemed like I have to understand what I should have done but didn't. So you say I should have flagged it as off-topic because the author did not provide an example of the expected result, if I am understanding correctly?

Comment: That isn't what you phrase the qusetion as though, @ArSen. As the title says, this qusetion is asking *"When is a homework help question off-topic?"*, not "Why did I receive a Review Ban?" thus the duplicate are for the qusetion ask. I would edit your question a bit to reflect that. You'll need yivi to unlock, or 5 users will need to vote to reopen though, after you edit it.

Comment: I was trying to understand the reasons behind the ban and my guess was that it was related to an (possibly) homework question taking care of in the wrong manner. But I get your point, will edit.

Comment: Edit your question do you ask one thing at a time. You are asking two unrelated questions, at least.

Comment: You selected “looks ok” for a question that does not look ok. Do you believe the question is fine and it’s answerable in its current form? If you did, then you would have thought the question “required editing”; since even if it were answerable it would benefit from polishing and trimming. Of course, that would be a wrong choice as well because the question should be closed. But in no scenario “looks ok” was a reasonable choice.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work?cb=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question you cited is a clear example of the general form of an "I've written some code but it doesn't work" question.  You need to be able to recognize these kinds of questions.  Eric Lippert [describes this problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) in detail on his blog, and what the general solution is.

More specifically, the problem with the specific question you cited is "I've written some code, can you finish it for me?"  The problems with that should be obvious.  Their question (and any answer that we provide) won't help anyone else but the person asking the question, and we don't provide extended tutoring here.

This is true no matter how specific they've made their question, whether or not it is a homework problem.

Comment: This answers my question exactly - and even after it was booed so much, thanks a bunch!