# Triage - no minimal example given

Tags: discussion, flags, triage

When triaging questions, which category should be chosen for users that have made no attempt to distill their question down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

For example, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466033/is-there-any-idea-so-that-i-can-close-my-javafx-app-automatically) , the OP has pasted multiple files of code.

Is the "needs more focus" flag the one that should be used for giant slabs of code?

Comment: Are they necessary to understand the issue in full? (How do you know they've made "no attempt to distill" it? It could have been 10 times bigger, no? :-)

Comment: If there has been any effort at all, it has been minimal.

Comment: I'd say it's still "Needs debugging details" because the main cause of that is no [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)

Answer (score 10):

Having too much code is better than (or, not as bad as) having not enough. Unless you're familiar with the tech, you may not be able to determine right away if the code is too much, or if it actually takes that much code to put together a minimal example because the problem is just that involved. Does the code just look like a whole lot of boilerplate, for example? If so, "needs debugging details" would work. Otherwise, I'd lean towards triaging the question as "needs community edit" over flagging it.

"Needs more focus", as the description suggests, is used for questions where there's too many unrelated questions, or otherwise too much going on in the *text*, not in the code, to determine exactly what the question is *asking*. This question seems pretty straightforward based on the problem statement, so that close reason wouldn't be a good fit.

Comment: "Having too much code is better than (or, not as bad as) having not enough." Completely disagree - a question that's a dump of the user's entire project is invariably garbage, and as such I don't even bother with such questions anymore (not even downvoting/VTC, because that would require me to read and understand the damn thing). OTOH, an objectively equally bad question that's too short will at least get a glance from me, and that's often enough to at least leave a comment and/or DV/VTC if merited. There's a very good reason why "minimal" is the first word in MCVE.

Comment: *"Having too much code is better than (or, not as bad as) having not enough."* - It's true sometimes, but not nearly often enough to make it a general rule.