# What am I doing wrong when I ask questions?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

What am I doing wrong when I ask questions?

This is an example of a deleted question where a user said I didn't have enough code so I added it.

> ## Scrap data from apt output
>
> I want grap data from apt output to my setup script i was able take
>
> ```python
> before_slash = re.compile(r"^.*?(?=\/)")
> ```
>
> But grap short desription without `\s\s` i can't.
> I tried:
>
> ```regex
> ^\s\s\w.*
> (?:\s\s)\b\w.*\b$\n
> ```
>
> alo i dont know how to grap description: from `apt show <package>`
>
> My code
>
> ```python
> #!/usr/bin/env python3
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
>
> __author__ = "heavyblack"
> __license__ = "GPLv3"
> __version__ = "0.1"
> __email__ = "heavyblack@gmail.com"
>
> import subprocess as sp
> import re
> import fire
> import yaml as y
>
>
> def packages_db_command (search,packages_db,yaml,long):
>     """
>     Write in to txt Note: long description is optional:
>     sudo apt install -y <package> #<short_description> Description:<long_description>
>     """
>     if yaml:
>         with open(f"{search}.yaml","w",encoding="utf-8") as yf:
>             y.safe_dump(packages_db,yf)
>     else:
>         with open(f"{search}.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
>             for k,v in packages_db.items():
>                 short_description = ""
>                 long_description = ""
>                 for dk,dv in v.items():
>                     if dk == "short_description":
>                         short_description = dv
>                     else: 
>                         long_description = dv
>                 if long:
>                     file.write(f"sudo apt install -y {k} #{short_description} # {long_description}\n")
>                 else:
>                     file.write(f"sudo apt install -y {k} #{short_description}\n")
>
>
> def main(search=True,yaml=False,long=False,fancy=False):
>     """
>     if --yaml you dont need --long
>     """
>     search = "games"
>
>     packages_binary = sp.run(["apt","search",search],capture_output=True)
>
>     packages = packages_binary.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
>
>     before_slash = re.compile(r"^.*?(?=\/)")
>     # This is my bad pattern which also select spaces which i dont want
>     short_description = re.compile(r"^\s\s\w.*")
>
>     packages_list = []
>     for re_item in packages: 
>         packages_list += re.findall(before_slash,re_item)
>
>     print(packages_list)
>
>     packages_list_short_description = []
>     for re_item in packages:
>         packages_list_short_description += re.findall(short_description,re_item)
>     
>     print(packages_list_short_description)
>
>     packages_db = {}
>     for package, packages_short_description in zip(packages_list,packages_list_short_description):
>         long_description_binary = sp.run(["apt","show",package],capture_output=True)
>         package_description_list = long_description_binary.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()
>
>         long_description_pattern = re.compile(r"<I dont know pattern for grap description>")
>         long_description_match = re.search(long_description_pattern,package_description_list)
>         long_description = long_description_match.string
>
>         package_content = {}
>         package_content["short_description"] = packages_short_description
>         package_content["long_description"] = long_description
>
>         packages_db[package] = package_content
>
>     packages_db_command(search,packages_db,yaml,long)
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     fire.Fire(main)
> ```

2. Second example:

> ## Python f-string align to column
>
> Hello i have my apt search scrape regex script but is not formating output right.
> In value first_column_max_length is length of first column
>
> ### Broken output
>
> ```bash
> sudo apt install -y xbomb #  'minesweeper' game with squares, hexagons or triangles                                                                                             
> sudo apt install -y xjig #  X11 jigsaw puzzle                                                                                                                                  
> sudo apt install -y xjump #  jumping game for X                                                                                                                                 
> sudo apt install -y xoreos-tools #  collection of tools around BioWare's Aurora engine games
> ```
>
> ### Output of what i want
>
> ```bash
> sudo apt install -y xbomb           #  'minesweeper' game with squares, hexagons or triangles                                                                                             
> sudo apt install -y xjig            #  X11 jigsaw puzzle                                                                                                                                  
> sudo apt install -y xjump           #  jumping game for X                                                                                                                                 
> sudo apt install -y xoreos-tools    #  collection of tools around BioWare's Aurora engine games
> ```
>
> ### My code
>
> `k is package name`
> `first_column_max_length is length of install command + package name`
>
> ```python
> for k,v in packages_db.items():
>     file.write(f"sudo apt install -y {k} {'#'+short_description : ^first_column_max_length}\n")
> ```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong that people do not answer or delete my questions?

Comment: If you want to ask about why your question was closed on [main] link to the question, don't just duplicate it here and give literally no context on the problem; including the close reason.

Comment: In the most polite way possible, I would recommend putting your question through a spell checker before you post it. People tend to not like it when people don't bother capitalising or spelling things correctly before they post.

Comment: _"or i am too autictic ask question?"_ If you mean "autistic", rest assured that there are many active users with some form of neurodivergence here, and have no trouble asking or answering.

Comment: @user438383 while that is *true*, I just want to make it clear to OP that wrong spelling is not a reason to close a question. In what I see above, there is not a single clear problem. I don't even know what is supposed to be fixed.

Comment: Note that we generally do not need *more code* – and especially not *all* code – but the *minimum code* that still *reproduces the issue*. See the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help page for guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions)

Comment: @VLAZ FWIW, without the link to the deleted questions, we can't know if the code was added before or after the deletion.

Comment: @AndrewT. I can only judge the thing I see posted here and it's unclear. If there was *no code* at the time of closure, it would also be unclear. I'm not sure why it was deleted, though - it doesn't seem that bad. Unless it was Roomba.

Comment: Given the quotes and Wai Ha Lee's edit, *this* question seems quite clear.  Even without the links, it's very obvious what's wrong with these questions.

Comment: Are you using machine translation to English (e.g., [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate))? A lot of your writing is incomprehensible (no amount of fixing grammar and spelling will help). Next worst is leaving out punctuation between sentences in a paragraph - don't do that. Are you from Pakistan (they are known to do that)? [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702566/how-to-set-the-default-python3-to-python3-9-in-linux-via-aliases/67703465#67703465): *"If you want better is update alternatives with this you can change default editor etc."*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are *really* unclear.

An incomplete list of issues:

**In general**

- Please please please take some time to spell check your post (pretty much all browsers have it built in, and there are free ones online if yours somehow doesn't), and to check the grammar.  If English isn't your first language, you can ask a friend for help, or there are sites that have automatic grammar checkers.  There are so many mistakes here that it's genuinely hard to figure out what you meant to say.

**First question**

- There's no information on what sort of input you're trying to parse.  `apt show firefox` on my system, for instance, doesn't output any "short description."
- "But grap short desription without `\s\s` i can't." isn't a clear description of a problem.  I don't have any idea what that means after several minutes of trying to guess.

**Second question**

- This could use a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It's missing the contents of `packages_db`, for instance.
- This is probably a duplicate of some question about string padding in Python.

Comment: "But grap short desription without \s\s i can't." - well "grap" is "grep", that much I can decode...